# What's the purpose of a ChangeNotifierProvider?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, inherited-widget, flutter-change-notifier-provider

According to flutter documentation, a `ChangeNotifierProvider`:

> Listens to a `ChangeNotifier`, expose[s] it to its descendants and rebuilds dependents whenever `ChangeNotifier.notifyListeners` is called.

and I was wondering ... why does this class exist?

I mean, wouldn't a `Provider<ChangeNotifier>` suffice that allows each subscriber to the notifier to decide for themselves whether or not they want to rebuild when `ChangeNotifier.notifyListeners` is called?

My gut feeling is that it's somehow related to stateless widgets, but then if the stateless widget needs to update based on some state further up the widget tree, shouldn't a change in that state trigger a rebuild on a sub-tree of some stateful widget that contains the stateless widget?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59883666/flutter-provider-changenotifierprovider-question Check this out

Comment: @Er1 thank you, you completely ignored the question and instead linked me some random question that sounded a bit similar but whose answer is the very thing that lead to the question you ignored.